# I keep trying to squash pushed commits but it affects other files

Tags: git, github

As you can see [via this github compare](https://github.com/airbnb/superset/compare/master...SalehHindi:remove-whitespace), I only changed one file but I made a bunch of commits that I'd like to squash into one commit. I tried following [this](https://github.com/ginatrapani/todo.txt-android/wiki/Squash-All-Commits-Related-to-a-Single-Issue-into-a-Single-Commit) article to try to squash the commits. Steps I took:

1. `git rebase -i HEAD~20`
2. Then replaced `pick` with `squash` in all the commits I wanted to squash.
3. I typed `git rebase --continue`.
4. As per the article, I had to force push my branch via `git push origin <branch name>` to the appropriate branch name.

However, when I compare the new changes to the branch I want to merge with, I see that the rebase affected 420 files that I never touched. Furthermore for the author of all those changes it now says `<original author> + <my name>` so it said I modified all of those files. Why did all of those files get affected? How am I squashing the commits incorrectly?

Comment: Your rebasing  first 20 commits from your head, is that you wanted to do?

Answer (score 1):

> As you can see via this github compare, I only changed one file

I don't know why github shows one file is changed, but a lot of these commits change other files. Many of them are also merges, which are a problem for `rebase`.

If you really want just this 1 file and there are no remaining changes to it in the master branch (if there are, merge first), I'd just do this:

```
git reset origin/master
git diff # verify that the only changes are to the file you want
git commit -am "Desired message"
```